# Printing to PDF from Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: python, pdf, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to share a few notebooks, and I think PDF is the best way to capture the functionality.
I'm aware that there is a lot under the hood for the "download as *PDF*" button in jupyter, and I've installed MikTex, NBConvert, and Pandoc. I'm wondering what else I'm missing?

```
nbconvert failed: PDF creating failed, captured latex output:

Failed to run "xelatex .\notebook.tex -quiet" command:

notebook.tex:168804: Undefined control sequence
notebook.tex:168804: Undefined control sequencemiktex-dvipdfmx: major issue: So far, you have not checked for MiKTeX updates.
```

That's my error when I go to download as PDF, but I erased some of the "undefined control sequence" lines for brevity.

Also, does printing as PDF keep my markdown formatting? I think it should, but not sure.

Comment: Did you get a chance to open MikTeX to update it as the message states?

Comment: I just tested it on a Linux machine, and wow, it's really beautiful output. It says pandoc is required for the Markdown, and it renders that as expected.

Comment: So it did update, but now when I go to 'check updates' again, it times out. When I run the print pdf command, now gives me: ```Failed to run "xelatex .\notebook.tex -quiet" command:```

Comment: Perusing some links related to that error leads me to believe that some packages need to be installed in LaTeX; however, I did not find a comprehensive list of those packages anywhere.

Comment: No worries, will probably just try to use HTML from now on. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: No prob. One of the links I saw mentioned using your browser's Print/Save to PDF functionality. You could try that...